# How to assign row names to a reactive data frame in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to do something that is quite simple to achieve in R script but I am struggling to replicate when part of a Shiny app. I am reading a file using ‘reactive({})’ (this part in the test code provided below has been replaced with test dataset, lines 13-16). I would like to take variable ‘Species’ entries and assign them to the data frame row names. I have tried two approaches

1. Inside the “reactive({})” statement, lines 13-16
2. By creating a new data frame df1, lines 18-20

but both ways don’t work for some reason.

Big thank you in advance!

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(datasets)

ui <-  basicPage("",
  DT::dataTableOutput("table"),
  verbatimTextOutput("head1"),
  verbatimTextOutput("head2")
)

server <-  function(input, output, session) {
  
  df <- reactive({
    df <- data.frame(v1=c("a", "b"), v2=c(10,20))
#    row.names(df) <- df[,1]           # THIS DOES NOT WORK
  })
  
  df1 <- reactive({                    # THIS ALSO DOESN'T WORK
    row.names(df()) <- df()[,1]
  })

  # Show data in a table ----
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      {df()}, 
      filter = 'top', 
      class="cell-border stripe", 
      rownames = TRUE
    ) # end of datatable
  })
  
  output$head1 <- renderPrint({
    head(df())
  })
  
  output$head2 <- renderPrint({
    head(df1())
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Are you sure that it works in R without shiny? I get the error that double row.names (non unique) are not allowed, try it e.g. with `testdf <- iris; row.names(testdf) <- testdf$Species`

Comment: @starja - Hmm, you are right, must be something to do with the dataset because this one works:``` r
df <- data.frame(v1=c("a", "b"), v2=c(10,20))

head(df)
#>   v1 v2
#> 1  a 10
#> 2  b 20
df <- as.data.frame(df)
row.names(df) <- df[,1]

head(df)
#>   v1 v2
#> a  a 10
#> b  b 20
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: @starja - I changed the data frame in the original question with one that works OK when using R script but fails as a Shiny implementation. Not sure why the iris dataset behaved differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(datasets)

ui <-  basicPage("",
                 DTOutput("table"),
                 DTOutput("head1"),
                 DTOutput("head2")
)

server <-  function(input, output, session) {
  
  df <- reactive({
    df <- data.frame(v1=c("a", "b"), v2=c(10,20))
    row.names(df) <- df[,1]           # THIS WORKs
    df
  })
  
  df1 <- reactive({                    # THIS ALSO WORKs
    data <- df()
    row.names(data) <- df()[,1]
    data
  })
  
  # Show data in a table ----
  output$table <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      {df()}, 
      filter = 'top', 
      class="cell-border stripe", 
      rownames = TRUE
    ) # end of datatable
  })
  
  output$head1 <- renderDT({
    head(df())
  })
  
  output$head2 <- renderDT({
    head(df1())
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: why it works: `reactive`s are like functions, so the value of the `reactive` is the return value/last value in your function. If the rowname setting is the last value in the function, it leads to problems, therefore you have to return the actual data.frame at last